# Transform Piecewise[] into sum of indicators

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, piecewise, conversion

I'm interested in transforming a piecewise defined function into a sum of indicator functions, ultimately with the aim to be better able to integrate them.

As an example I would like to transform the function

```
f = Piecewise[{{x, 3*x > y && x < 2*y}, {y, 2*x > y && x < 3*y}}, 0]
```

into

```
x Boole[3 x > y && x < 2 y] + y Boole[x >= 2 y && x < 3 y].
```

For this specific example, this could be achieved by

```
f[[1,1,1]]Boole[f[[1,1,2]]] + f[[1,2,1]]Boole[f[[1,2,2]] && !f[[1,1,2]]]
```

but I don't know how to efficiently generalize this to functions with more than two cases, in particular how to ensure that the term corresponding to the $n$th case contains the negated conditions of the first $n-1$ cases.

In a second step, assuming that the conditions of the piecewise function are linear inequalities, I would like to decompose each Boole[] into a sum of Boole[]'s of disjoint intervals for, say, the variable $x$.

In my example above this would mean

```
Boole[3 x > y && x < 2 y] == Boole[y/3 < x < y/2]
Boole[x >= 2 y && x < 3 y] == Boole[2y < x < 3y]
```

This is maybe a trivial example, but in more complex situations one will have to deal with more than one disjoint interval.
In non-Mathematica notation I'd like a decomposition of the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_i f_i(x) \sum_j\mathbf{1}_{\left\{x_{i,j}^{\min}<x<x_{i,j}^\max\right\}}(x).
$$
where the $f_i$ are given by `f[[1,All,1]]`.

Comment: For a start you can try `Cases[Piecewise[{{x, 3*x > y && x < 2*y}, {y, 2*x > y && x < 3*y}}, 
   0] /. Piecewise -> Plus, {a_, b_} -> a Boole[b]]`

Comment: Thanks @Blackbird: Does your method also give the correct result if the conditions of the piecewise function are not mutually exclusive? In the example, if `x < 2y && 2x > y` I think your result would give `{x,y}` (or `x+y`) whereas the original function would evaluate to `x` because of sequential evaluation of cases.

Comment: Try to run above snippet and do %/.{x->2,y->4}.I didn't actually understand this mutual exclusion you said,but may be this helps.

Comment: `%/.{x->2,y->3}` gives `{2,3}`

Comment: Boole is deciding what you will get so, may be you need correct combination of x,y that you get only one +ive numerical result,eg {x->2,y->4} .This will get you {2,0}.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to obtain an expression that gives the same result for all values of `x` and `y`, though.

Comment: `Boole` returns `True` or `False`, but you have x,y multiplied, so how can result be same ? Or you might be saying same as x,y per x,y replaced. For example {x->1,y->1} returns {1,1}.

Comment: In Mathematica, `Boole[]` returns `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making up a three-piece function,

```
f = Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}, {x^2, 0 <= x < 3}, {x^3, 3 <= x}}, 0];
```

we can map `Boole` onto the conditions of `f` and use `Dot` to sum the products of the values and the 0/1 values of the conditions thus:

```
Dot @@ MapAt[Boole, Transpose @ First @ f, 2]
(* x^2 Boole[0 <= x < 3] + x Boole[x < 0] + x^3 Boole[3 <= x] *)
```

Check:

```
% /. x -> 2
(* 4 *)
```

---

**Update**

To get an expression that is equivalent to `Piecewise`, one needs to nest the expressions similar to the psuedo-formula

```
Boole[cond] exp + (1 - Boole[cond]) (rest)
```

Example:

```
f2 = Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}, {x^2, 0 < x < 3}, {x^3, 2 <= x}}, 1000];

f2exp = Fold[(1 - Boole[Last @ #2]) #1 + Boole[Last @ #2] First[#2] &, 
             Last @ f2, Reverse @ First @ f2]
(* x Boole[x < 0] +
    (1 - Boole[x < 0]) (x^2 Boole[0 < x < 3] +
     (1 - Boole[0 < x < 3]) (1000 (1 - Boole[3 <= x]) + x^3 Boole[2 <= x])) *)

Table[f2 /. x -> i, {i, -1, 4}]
Table[f2exp /. x -> i, {i, -1, 4}]
(* {-1, 1000, 1, 4, 27, 64} *)
(* {-1, 1000, 1, 4, 27, 64} *)
```

Note the default value for `x = 0`.

Comment: Thank you. Would this work if the conditions of the piecewise function are not mutually exclusive, as in your example.

Comment: No, it wouldn't produce a expression equivalent to `Piecewise` if the conditions were not mutually exclusive, for the same reason that the method in your example would not work: Order matters in `Piecewise` but not in `Plus`.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to express `Piecewise` in terms of `UnitStep`.

```
In[1]:= f = Piecewise[{{x,3*x>y&&x<2*y},{y,2*x>y&&x<3*y}},0];

In[2]:= Simplify`PWToUnitStep[f]
Out[2]= x (1-UnitStep[x-2 y]) (1-UnitStep[-3 x+y])+
          y ((1-UnitStep[x-3 y]) UnitStep[x-2 y] (1-UnitStep[-2 x+y])+(1-UnitStep[x-3 y]) 
          UnitStep[-3 x+y] (1-UnitStep[-2 x+y])-(1-UnitStep[x-3 y])^2 UnitStep[x-2 y] 
          UnitStep[-3 x+y] (1-UnitStep[-2 x+y])^2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this usage documented anywhere? Also, the expression multiplying `y` seems quite complicated. Can it be further simplified? `Simplify` transforms the expression back into its piecewise form.

Comment: This is an undocumented function.

Comment: I don't think it can be simplified further. Trying `Simplify[x (1 - UnitStep[x - 2 y]) (1 - UnitStep[-3 x + y]) + 
  y ((1 - UnitStep[x - 3 y]) UnitStep[
       x - 2 y] (1 - UnitStep[-2 x + y]) + (1 - 
        UnitStep[x - 3 y]) UnitStep[-3 x + y] (1 - 
        UnitStep[-2 x + y]) - (1 - UnitStep[x - 3 y])^2 UnitStep[
       x - 2 y] UnitStep[-3 x + y] (1 - UnitStep[-2 x + y])^2), 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
     10^4 Count[#, _Piecewise, {0, \[Infinity]}] &)]` doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
Dot @@ {Boole /@ #, #2} & @@ Internal`FromPiecewise[f]
```

or

```
Dot @@ MapAt[Boole, Internal`FromPiecewise[f], 1] (* thanks: @J.M.*)
```

> y Boole[2 x > y && x < 3 y] + x Boole[3 x > y && x < 2 y]

Comment: Equivalently: ``Dot @@ MapAt[Boole, Internal`FromPiecewise[f], 1]``.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand) to make sure the conditions are disjoint. For your example:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x, 3*x > y && x < 2*y}, {y, 2*x > y && x < 3*y}}, 0];
disjoint = PiecewiseExpand[
    pw,
    Method -> {"OrderlessConditions"->True, "ConditionSimplifier"->FullSimplify}
];
disjoint //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  x & 3 x>y\land x<2 y \\
>  y & x\geq 2 y\land x<3 y
> \end{cases}$

Since the default is `0`, you can easily convert the output to your desired sum of [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole) form:

```
bool = Replace[
    disjoint,
    HoldPattern @ Piecewise[c_, d_] :> Total @ Replace[c, {a_, b_} :> a Boole[b], {1}]
]
```

> x Boole[3 x > y && x < 2 y] + y Boole[x >= 2 y && x < 3 y]

Check:

```
FullSimplify[pw == bool, (x|y) \[Element] Reals]
```

> True

However, if the default isn't zero, than the above won't work. It is possible to patch things up by negating all of the non-default conditions and adding a [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole) term for the default. But instead, I will suggest a small modification of @kglr's answer. His answer used the internal, undocumented function `` Internal`FromPiecewise ``. The problem with his answer is that one argument usage of `` Internal`FromPiecewise `` will not properly handle non-disjoint conditions. Instead, when there are non-disjoint conditions, you need to use the two argument version. Consider a small modification of Michael's example:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x, x < 0}, {x^2, 0 < x < 3}, {x^3, 2 <= x}}, 1000];
pw //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  x & x<0 \\
>  x^2 & 0<x<3 \\
>  x^3 & 2\leq x \\
>  1000 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Using the one argument version:

```
kglr = Dot @@ MapAt[Boole, Internal`FromPiecewise[pw], 1]
```

> 1000 + x Boole[x < 0] + x^2 Boole[0 < x < 3] + x^3 Boole[2 <= x]

This result is not equal to the original [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) expression:

```
FindInstance[pw != kglr, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -1, y -> 0}}

Using the two argument version:

```
s = Dot @@ MapAt[Boole, Internal`FromPiecewise[pw, True], 1]
```

> x^2 Boole[x > 0 && x < 3] + 1000 Boole[x == 0] + x^3 Boole[x >= 3] + 
>    x Boole[x < 0]

Check that the result is equal to the original [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) expression:

```
FullSimplify[pw == s, (x|y) \[Element] Reals]
```

> True

So, a function that converts piecewise expressions to a sum of indicator functions would be:

```
sumOfBoole[pw_Piecewise] := Dot @@ MapAt[
    Boole @* FullSimplify,
    Internal`FromPiecewise[pw, True],
    1
]
```

where I also included a [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) call. Michael's example again:

```
sumOfBoole[pw]
```

> 1000 Boole[x == 0] + x^3 Boole[x >= 3] + x^2 Boole[0 < x < 3] + x Boole[x < 0]