# Problem with Integrate with Piecewise and PrincipalValue

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, piecewise

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

In the course of developing an alternative solution for question [127301](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127303/1063),

With,

```
$Version
(* "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)" *)
```

I attempted to perform the integral,

```
um = -(2/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) - (2 u)/3 + u^2/3;
up = -(10/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) + (8 u)/3 - u^2/3;
sv = Piecewise[{{um, u <= 1}, {up, u > 1}}];
Integrate[sv, {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

but received the error message,

> Integrate: Integral of ... does not converge on {0,2}.

Separating the term, `-(2/(3 (-1 + u)))`, does not help.

```
sv1 = Piecewise[{{um + 2/(3 (-1 + u)), u <= 1}, {up + 2/(3 (-1 + u)), u > 1}}];
Integrate[sv1 - 2/(3 (-1 + u)), {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

yielding the same error message.  Yet,

```
Integrate[sv1, {u, 0, 2}] - 
    Integrate[2/(3 (-1 + u)), {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* -1 *)
```

does work.  (The second integral equals `0`, incidentally.)  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?  Thanks.

(Note that 10.4.1 produces the same results.)

**Addendum: Workaround**

Slightly shifting the `Piecewise` boundary at `u = 1` so that the singular point lies within one or the other segment gives an accurate result.  For instance, redefining `sv` as

```
sv = Piecewise[{{um, u <= 1 + 10^-10}, {up, u > 1 + 10^-10}}];
```

allows `sv` to be integrated by `Integrate`.

```
Integrate[sv, {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True] // FullSimplify
(* -(4500000000000000000044999999999/4500000000000000000000000000000) *)
```

which is `1.` to 20 significant figures.  That this occurs is consistent with the suggestion by [MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) that `Integrate` integrates each segment of `Piecewise` independently and, therefore, cannot handle singularities at the boundary between two segments.  Nonetheless, I believe that it should be able to.  Failing that, the documentation should describe this limitation.

Comment: w/ v10.1 they just return unevaluated, no error message.

Comment: @george2079  Thanks for the additional information.  Also, your comment remained me to add my own `$Version` information.

Comment: My guess is that `PiecewiseExpand` is applied to the integrand, the integral of the resulting `Piecewise` function is broken up according to the pieces, and the principal value of ***each piece*** is computed.  And the integrals of the pieces diverge. FWIW, `GenerateConditions -> False` gives the right answer **plus** half the contribution of the pole at `u == 1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Your guess seems credible, especially because I now see that moving the boundary to `1.001` (for instance) gives a reasonable result.  But `Integrate` should recognize a singularity at the boundary between two pieces of `Piecewise` and with `PrincipalValue -> True` attempt to match it with a singularity at the other side of the boundary (obtained using `Series`, perhaps).  If it cannot, the documentation should say so.

Comment: `Re@Integrate[sv, {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True, GenerateConditions -> False]` seems nearly satisfactory to me, given the pole makes a predictably purely imaginary contribution; but maybe my standards for symbolic integration are low. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a bug, because if we transform the `Piecewise` function into a combination of `UnitStep` (which is mathematically equivalent to the original function of course), `Integrate` integrates without difficulty:

```
um = -(2/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) - (2 u)/3 + u^2/3;
up = -(10/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) + (8 u)/3 - u^2/3;
sv = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{um, u <= 1}, {up, u > 1}}];
Integrate[sv, {u, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True]
(* -1 *)
```

Tested on *v9.0.1* and *v11.2*.

Comment: Excellent explanation and workaround.  Thanks.  I see that `Simplify` has a large family of sub-functions.  Are they documented anywhere?

Comment: @bbgodfrey As far as I know, they're all undocumented… I learned the usage of ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep`` by (accidentally) reading [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33554/1871).

Answer (score 2):

Another way. Integrate from both sides to small r near the singularity and let r go to zero.

```
um = -(2/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) - (2 u)/3 + u^2/3;
up = -(10/3) - 2/(3 (-1 + u)) + (8 u)/3 - u^2/3;
sv[u_] = Piecewise[{{um, u <= 1}, {up, u > 1}}];

int = Integrate[sv[u], {u, 0, 1 - r}, Assumptions -> 0 < r < 1] + 
      Integrate[sv[u], {u, 1 + r, 2}, Assumptions -> 0 < r < 1]

(*   1/9 (-8 + 9 r - r^3 - 6 Log[r]) + 
     1/9 (-1 + 9 r - 9 r^2 + r^3 + 6 Log[r])   *)

Limit[int, r -> 0, Direction -> -1]

(*   -1   *)
```