# ElementwiseLayer with Piecewise?

Tags: machine-learning, piecewise, neural-networks

I need a specific custom activation function; how can I implement it with `Piecewise`?

This is what I've tried (using the recommendation from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146569/how-to-make-advanced-activations-layers-in-mathematica)):

```
p = Function[x, Piecewise[{{Exp[x] - (2 + E)/(2 E), x < -1}, {x/2, x < 0}, {x, 
 x > 0}}], Listable]
ElementwiseLayer[p]
```

[image]

Is there a systematic workaround to handle the conversion from an aribitrary `Piecewise` function into an `ElementwiseLayer`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Advanced Activations Layers in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146569/how-to-make-advanced-activations-layers-in-mathematica)

Comment: @NikiEstner that question is similar but doesn't actually address the general case of any Piecewise condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give a general method for re-expressing a `Piecewise[]` expression. This hinges on two things. First:

```
FullSimplify[1 - Sign[Ramp[-x]] == UnitStep[x], x ∈ Reals]
   True
```

The second part is that in principle, any piecewise expression can be re-expressed in terms of `UnitStep[]`; in particular, there is the *undocumented* function `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep[] `` (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33554)) for performing the conversion.

With these two considerations (and using a less trivial example):

```
Simplify`PWToUnitStep[Piecewise[{{2 - #, # <= 0}, {# + 1, # > 0}}] &[x]] /.
UnitStep -> (1 - Sign[Ramp[-#]] &)
   (2 - x) (1 - Sign[Ramp[x]]) + (1 + x) Sign[Ramp[x]]
```

and now one can do `ElementwiseLayer[Function[x, (2 - x) (1 - Sign[Ramp[x]]) + (1 + x) Sign[Ramp[x]]]]`.

Comment: thanks for a simple generalizable explanation!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `ElementwiseLayer`:

> The function f can be any one of the following: Ramp, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, ArcTan, ArcTanh, Sin, Sinh, ArcSin, ArcSinh, Cos, Cosh, ArcCos, ArcCosh, Log, Exp, Sqrt, Abs, Gamma, LogGamma.
>
> In general, f can be any object that when applied to a single argument gives any combination of Ramp, LogisticSigmoid, etc., together with Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power, Min, Max, Clip, and numbers.

So you'll need to use something like `ElementwiseLayer[Ramp[#] - Ramp[-#] &]`